# Incrementing every other iteration of for loop (JAVA)

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

I want to make a for loop that adds by 1 every other iteration, as long as it doesn't reach a value higher than 5.
I've tried with nested forloops but it's still nothing like it.

E.g.
Given a value x=10 or x=3.

```
     For i<x && i<=5; i++
```

and this is where i want a value y, to be added with +1 every other (2th) time it runs the loop.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by “every other iteration”?

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: @cdauth every second time it iterates over the loop

Answer (score 1):

You can do this for example by adding a second variable `s` that is `0` on every first and `1` on every second iteration.

```
for(int i=0, s=0; i<5; i+=s, s=-s+1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `%` (module) operator in a condition inside the loop with the index variable, like this:

```
// code where you initialize x and y variables

for (int i=0; i<x && i<=5; i++) {
    if (i % 2 == 0) { // even values for i
        y++; 
    }
}
```

In this case the loop increments `y` in the first, third, fifth (.. and so on) iterations. If you want to increment it on the second, fourth, sixth (... and so on), then invert the condition with `i % 2 != 0`